# Integral operator and eigenvalues

Tags: functional-analysis

Let $T:L^2[0,1]\to L^2[0,1]$ be a compact self-adjoint operator, and let $(\lambda_n)$ be the non-zero eigenvalues of $T$ 
a) Show that $T$ is the integral operator associated to some $k\in L^2([0,1]\times [0,1])$ if and only if 
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda_n|^2<\infty.
$$

b) Use (a) to show that there are compact self-adjoint operators on $L^2[0,1]$ that are not integral operators associated to functions in $L^2([0,1]\times [0,1])$.

I'm having trouble working out what to do with this.

I have that $T$ is an integral operator associated with $k$ is defined as $(T_ku)(y)=\int_0^1k(x,y)u(y)dy$ where $\|T_k\|_{\mathcal{B(L^2[0,1]})}\leq\|k\|_{L^2([0,1]\times[0,1])}$

If
$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty |\lambda_n|^2<\infty.
$
Then, taking $e_n$ to be the normalized eigenvector assocated to $\lambda_n$. 
I think I want to take
$k(x,y):=\sum\limits_{n=1}^\infty\lambda_n e_n(x)\overline{e_n}(y)$. 
But I'm not sure what to do after this.

Comment: Be sure to choose representatives $e_n$ (as functions) first so that $e_n(x)$ has a meaning. Then set $k_n(x,y) := e_n(x)\overline{e_n(y)}$. Prove that $(k_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ is an orthonormal system in $L^2([0,1]^2)$. Then set $k := \sum_n\lambda_n k_n$ (convergence in the sense of $L^2([0,1]^2)$). Now you can go on proving that indeed $Tu = \sum_n\lambda_n\langle u,e_n\rangle e_n = \int_0^1 k(x,y)u(y)\,dy$.

Comment: How do we how that $k$ as defined makes sense in $L^2([0,1]^2)$?

Comment: Because $(k_n)$ is orthonormal. Use a standard Cauchy argument to see that the series converges.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't done series in such a long time. I want to show there exist an $N$ such that if $m,n>N$ then $\|\sum\limits_{k=m}^n\lambda_nk_n\|_{L^2[0,1]^2}<\epsilon$?

Comment: Square both sides and use the orthonormality.

Comment: Any suggestions for showing part b?

Comment: Choose, e.g., $\lambda_n = 1/\sqrt n$.